# Java - StringIndexOutOfBounds exception in anchor tag web crawler

Tags: java, string, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a web crawler that takes a URL address, and crawls the page for anchor tags in the html `<a href="...>`, it will then crawl each of the links in the arraylist that's produced from the first crawl through. I have to get everything from in between the double quotations in the anchor tag after the href, `<a href="needtogetthisdata"></a>`and also convert it to an absolute path before storing it as a link. I do this by using `.getHost()`on the original url, and passing it to a method `getAbsolutePath()` which checks if the path contains http or https, or if it begins with a '/', incase it's already an absolute path, or root path. In either case, I concatenate a string with what's required. So I would be left with something like `"http://" + hostname + '/' + hrefPath` which could return a string like `http://www.oracle.com/hrefPath` The problem is that when indexing the string to either get a substring or the absolute path name, I'm getting a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` but I am not understanding how this is happening?

I'm testing it with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, FileNotFoundException {

   CrawlerEng myCrawlerEngine = new CrawlerEng();
   myCrawlerEngine.open("http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/features/business-by-design");
   myCrawlerEngine.follow(100);
   myCrawlerEngine.save2Html("output.html");
   }
}
```

And to read the data:

```
//Make a connection with the specified url
   public void open(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
      address = new URL(url);
      conn = address.openConnection();
   }  

   //Loads the content of the page, finds links and stores them in the ArrayList
   public void follow() throws IOException {
      InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
      Scanner in = new Scanner(stream);

      in.useDelimiter("<a");
      while(in.hasNext()) {

         UrlPath current = new UrlPath(in.next());
         String absPath = current.getAbsolutePath(address.getHost());
         Link link = new Link(absPath);
         list.add(link);
      } 
      in.close();   
   }
```

And for the path:

```
public class UrlPath {

   private String path;

   public UrlPath(String path) {

      int hrefIndex = path.indexOf("href=");
      int start = path.indexOf("\"", hrefIndex);
      int end = path.indexOf("\"", start + 1);
      this.path = path.substring(start + 1, end);
   }

   public String getAbsolutePath(String host) {

      if(path.contains("http") || path.contains("https")) 
         return path;
      else if(path.charAt(0) == '/')
         return  "http://" + host + path;
      else
         return "http://" + host + '/' + path;  
   }     
}
```

The exception occurs at 0, in charAt 0 in the getAbsolutePath method, which leads me to believe for some reason the string empty. Otherwise wouldn't it return a null pointer exception if the string was never initialized?

To clarify further, the question is **not** asking what is a `StringIndexOutOfBounds` but it is asking why is it happening in this circumstance. Thank you

Comment: Your code appears to be running without any errors, at least the reduced version which I just tested in IntelliJ.  You might want to include a stack trace here.

Comment: You stuck a nerve with that comment, I realized that in the reduced version it's not iterating over as many links as it is in the full version. I reduced the "limit" that's being passed as a parameter to the follow method and it works for me. I just need to add a few conditions so it will work with a higher amount of link depending on the contnts of the href

Comment: Glad to help (did I actually help you?).

Comment: Haha yes you did, you put my thoughts on track